# Testing with Sinon-Chai that an individual callback in a Node JS Express route with multiple callbacks is called

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I'm relatively new to Node and Sinon. This application was made with Express, and I'm using Mocha, Chai, and Sinon. Using Sinon-Chai, I'm POST testing routes in Express with multiple callbacks, and can't figure out how to check second and subsequent callbacks.

The route inside my index.js is:

```
var controller = require('./example.controller');
var validator = require('./example.validator');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', validator.create, controller.create);
```

In my validator.js is the validator.create which checks the submitted parameter:

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
  var valid = true;
  var errorMessages = [];

  if (req.body.name) {
    patt = /[^a-zA-Z0-9 !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':]/g;
    if (patt.test(req.body.name)) {
      valid = false;
      errorMessages.push("Parameter is not alphanumeric");
    }
  }

  if (valid == false) {
    return res.status(400).json(errorMessages);
  }

  next();
}
```

In my controller.js is the controller.create which creates a entry in the DB:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    return Example.create(req.body)
        .then(baseController.respondWithResult(res, 201))
        .catch(baseController.handleError(res));
}
```

The Sinon-Chai tests in my index.spec.js:

```
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noPreserveCache();   

var exampleCtrlStub = {
    create: 'exampleCtrl.create',
};

var exampleValidatorStub = {
    create: 'exampleValidator.create'
}

var routerStub = {
    get: sinon.spy(),
    put: sinon.spy(),
    patch: sinon.spy(),
    post: sinon.spy(),
    delete: sinon.spy()
};

var exampleIndex = proxyquire('./index.js', {
    express: {
        Router() {
            return routerStub;
        }
    },
    './example.controller': exampleCtrlStub,
    './example.validator': exampleValidatorStub
});

describe('POST /api/examples', function() {
    it('should route to example.validator.create', function() {
        routerStub.post
            .withArgs('/', 'exampleValidator.create')
            .should.have.been.calledOnce;
    });
});


describe('POST /api/examples', function() {
    it('should route to example.controller.create', function() {
        routerStub.post
            .withArgs('/', 'exampleCtrl.create')
            .should.have.been.called;
    });
});
```

Though expecting both tests to pass, the first test (validator.create) passes but the second one (controller.create) fails. I've not been able to find a way to test that the controller.create is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the second test, we can't skip the first validator argument using `withArgs`. The test is failed because it is looking for a method with this signature which is not exist in source.

```
router.post('/', controller.create);
```

`withArgs` always start with the first then second argument, etc. So, the solution is to include the validator in the test

```
routerStub.post
  .withArgs('/', 'exampleValidator.create', 'exampleCtrl.create')
  .should.have.been.called;
```

Reference:

- https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.3/mocks/#expectationwithargsarg1-arg2-

Hope it helps

Comment: Perfect! This definitely helps. Thank you.